# logging setup best practices

Tags: java, logging

how do you go about structuring logging in your java projects?
I have used log4j2, logback etc, however this is not a question about libraries but about setup and best practices.

I have tried:

1. in filter

but it does not have enough detail. For example i cannot log method calls, input/output values in methods etc. Also it does not feel good when i need detailed logs of user activities.

2. in each class

In each class, a static field for the logger, then in methods where needed i log what i need to. This way i have all the detail i want, but it's a lot pf work and it feels like the code is littered with log stuff.

What do you use in your projects?

Thanks

Comment: If you only want method entry-exit logs, you can try AOP. But you want the logs from within a method, am not sure how you'd achieve without littering the code, as you'd put it.

Comment: I think your question is too broad and all answers that come back will be opinion-based. In other words: this is not a good question; it would be a good starting point for a **discussion**, but that is not what SO is for.

Comment: @Jägermeister I do not think this is a starting point for a discussion, neither am I asking for a this VS that approach. I simply want to know HOW others treat their logging needs. Also,i think  it's a pretty specific question, related to a pretty narrow field(i.e. logging).

Comment: @B11 Well, just check the two answers you got so far. You got opinions. And you will not get anything else; because there can't be one technical, covering-everything answer. You can only learn about the experiences other people have made. Some will be able to write up good helpful answers, others just throw links at you. Besides: "logging" is not only a field, it is a "whole discipline" (imho).

Answer (score 0):

I generally go with a similar approach to that of using static loggers in Class, but with a twist. Generally, I use only one static logger and a collection of Aspects. When a method requires to be logged, and usually it's input/output that needs to be logged, I simply use an @Around aspect. This keeps your code clean and separates the concerns of business logic with the concerns of the programmer (logging).

Here's a great place to start: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html